# v switch not working inside bash function (-v switch)

Tags: bash

I am using the -v switch to output a command in a bash script as it is run (it's a complicated multi-line command so I want to be able to make sure at run-time that it is correct). This has worked fine, but now I moved the command inside a bash function, and after that the -v switch no longer works. Is there any way to get this working?

I am aware of -x, which does work inside the function. But that prints the processed command, which is very hard to read (the original command includes some variables and such).

I could echo something manually, but the key thing is that I do not want to define the command once for output, and then again for the actual run – that would defeat the purpose of outputting it in case there was a mismatch between the two entries of the command.

Comment: About `-v`, the manual says *Print shell input lines as they are **read**.*. Definition of a function is read once, the shell doesn't read anything while executing it (the same goes for all compound commands, see [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-04/msg00171.html) for example). So, what do you mean *get this working*? It seems to work just as advertised.

Comment: I was not suggesting that there was a bug, just that it was not working for my use-case. Thank you for referencing that thread, it makes the issue pretty clear. Although one might note that since the definition of the function probably has to be read once, as you note, the command would be printed at that time, which it is not, at least not in this toy example.

fun_bla() {
    set -v
    ls
    set +v
}
fun_bla

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `trace` attribute together with the `trap` builtin. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

MYVAR='Expansion of my variable'

MyFunction () {
        echo Second $MYVAR
        echo Third $MYVAR
}

declare -f -t MyFunction

trap 'echo DEBUG: $BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG

echo First $MYVAR
MyFunction
echo Last $MYVAR
```

Here is the full output. Notice variables are not expanded in the debug output.

```
DEBUG: echo First $MYVAR
First Expansion of my variable
DEBUG: MyFunction
DEBUG: MyFunction
DEBUG: echo Second $MYVAR
Second Expansion of my variable
DEBUG: echo Third $MYVAR
Third Expansion of my variable
DEBUG: echo Last $MYVAR
Last Expansion of my variable
```